# Stop Google Chrome from storing username/form data

Tags: google-chrome, privacy

Google Chrome likes to store my usernames, and I'm not sure what other form data. I'm not sure how it works, but it is. (It does ask about passwords and I can tell it not to when it asks.)

How do I stop it from doing so?

I can delete them, choosing "clear form data" but I don't want them saved in the first place.

Is there a setting to tell it not to store form data?

I know there's an incognito window (which I find doesn't store extra data, and no doubt wouldn't store other things) but besides that, is there a way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Wrench > Options > Personal Stuff
2. Click on the **AutoFill Options** button in the *Form autofill* section.
3. Uncheck **Enable AutoFill to fill in web forms with a single click**.

This should now stop prompting you with previously entered values such as your name or email address when you go fill out a form.

Comment: In modern Chrome it is hidden under Settings -> Show Advanced -> Passwords and Forms